# Toggle feature visibility within layer efficiently

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Currently I am working on an interactive map of the ten most common tree species within the city. For the map I want users to be able to toggle the visibility of each of the ten species, plus an 'all other' species toggle.

The issue is that my current method to achieve this is very bloated, and could be significantly streamlined

Currently my method is to create a series of checked boxes

```
<input type='checkbox' id='checkbox0'checked> Check0 </input> <div></div>
<input type='checkbox' id='checkbox1'checked> Check1 </input> <div></div>
<input type='checkbox' id='checkbox2'checked> Check2 </input> <div></div>
...
<input type='checkbox' id='checkbox11'checked> Check11 </input> <div></div>
```

Add the layer for the trees and style the features within it:

```
 map.addLayer({
    id: 'wpgTrees',
    type: 'circle',
    source: {
      type: 'vector',
      url: 'url_Goes_Here'
    },
    'source-layer': 'source_Goes_Here',
    'paint': {
      'circle-radius': [
        'interpolate', ['linear'], ['zoom'],
        13, 2,
        20, 4,
      ],
        'circle-color':[
            'match',
            ['get','Common_Nam'],
            'green ash',        treeColours[0], // Bright red
            'American Elm',     treeColours[1], // Orange
            'Linden species',   treeColours[2], // Blue
            'Siberian Elm',     treeColours[3], //Light red
            'bur oak',          treeColours[4], //Green, purple
            'Manitoba maple, boxelder', treeColours[5],
            'black Ash',            treeColours[6], // pink
            'Colorado blue spruce', treeColours[7], // light blue
            'Poplar species',       treeColours[8], //light green
            'white spruce',         treeColours[9], //light puruple
            treeColours[10] //All Others
        ],
    }
});
```

Then use an addEventListener for each checkbox (0 to 10, for eleven layers) to set each feature's opacity using the .[setPaintProperty](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api#map#setpaintproperty).

```
checkbox0.addEventListener('click',function() {
    if(treeBoolean[0] == true) {
    treeOpacity[0]=0;
    treeBoolean[0] = !treeBoolean[0];
} else {
    treeOpacity[0]=1;
    treeBoolean[0] = !treeBoolean[0];
};
    map.setPaintProperty('wpgTrees','circle-opacity',[
        'match',
        ['get','Common_Nam'],
        'green ash', treeOpacity[0],
        'American Elm',     treeOpacity[1],
        'Linden species',   treeOpacity[2],
        'Siberian Elm',     treeOpacity[3],
        'bur oak',          treeOpacity[4],
        'Manitoba maple, boxelder', treeOpacity[5],
        'black Ash',            treeOpacity[6],
        'Colorado blue spruce', treeOpacity[7],
        'Poplar species',       treeOpacity[8],
        'white spruce',         treeOpacity[9],
        1,
    ]);
})
```

The issue with this method is that I will need to repeat the addEventListener section of code for all 11 types of features. There must be a better way of doing this, as my current method will is very 'bloated'.

Thank you for your time, and help.

Comment: Spread the data across the layers as in this example: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/filter-markers/

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but I am having difficulty seeing how to apply it to my example. The Filter Symbols example focuses on a Geojson, and it also applies filter syntax which the Style Specification notes is deprecated, and recommends using expression syntax instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be more efficient to add checked boxes and handlers in a loop. And also in a loop construct an expression for opacity. For example, if the type list looks like this:

```
var treesTypes = [
  {
    type: 'green ash',
    color: '#ff0000',
    visible: true
  },
  ... 
];
```

The expression for opacity can be obtained as follows:

```
var opacity = ["match", ["get", "Common_Nam"]];
treesTypes.forEach(function(treeType) {
  opacity.push(treeType.type);
  opacity.push(treeType.visible ? 1 : 0)
});
opacity.push(1);
map.setPaintProperty('wpgTrees', 'circle-opacity', opacity);
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/6pvnd5xm/1/ ]